# what's a close synonym for " sorted for Es and whiz"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

what's a close synonym for "sorted for Es and whiz"? and what does it mean in general? When And how can we use in conversation? is it polite or impolite or impolite?

Comment: I assume you've done a lot of research?

Comment: On the other hand, "sorted for Cheez Whiz" means that you've gone through all of the sandwiches in the picnic basket, and moved all of the ones that have "processed cheese food" as their main ingredient to the bottom of the basket.

Comment: Feels to me worth pointing out that the questions seems somewhat self-contradictory. Can't really see what conversation you would need to formally/politely announce that you are carrying drugs. Hardly one for the grandparents at Sunday dinner!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*E* is an abbreviation for *ecstasy*, a very potent drug. This abbreviation is very common, but it is slang.

*Wizz* is apparently a slang abbreviation for speed, another potent drug. I have personally never heard this slang term used in practice, so I would say it is at least *less* common than *E* for ecstasy is.

If you are [sorted (ODO, def. 1.2)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sorted) for something, then you are:

> *(Of a person)* prepared for or provided with something (especially illegal drugs)

In other words, if you are *sorted for E’s and wizz*, then you are all set and provided with what you need of ecstasy and speed.

According to [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorted_for_E's_%26_Wizz), the song (*Sorted for E’s and Wizz* by Pulp)

> describes going to a rave "somewhere in a field in Hampshire", taking drugs ("E's and Wizz" refers to ecstasy and speed). "Getting sorted" means having handled something, in this case, picking up drugs for a concert.

In an informal, colloquial setting where slang is to be expected, I would be perfectly confident in using *E* to refer to the drug ecstasy. I would not use *wizz*, but then again, I don’t know that term.

Being *sorted* is perfectly natural speech, most common in British English, and is not overly colloquial, except in the particular drug-related sense used here. It is not a turn of phrase you’d likely use in formal conversation, though.

I would never use the phrase as a whole in *any* context, unless I were quoting the song intentionally. It is not a fixed phrase or idiom, just a combination of colloquial and slang expressions.